# Python random card dealer - face card counter doesn't count correctly

Tags: python

I'm practicing writing this program for class. I have to deal cards until four aces are dealt and at the end, I also have to count how many face cards (jack, queen, king cards) were dealt. I didn't make a dictionary for the card names because my teacher specifically told us to do the random integer command. However, everything works except for the face counter (f_counter). It always counts one less face cards for some reason. Does anyone know why? Thanks!

```
print("You were dealt:\n")

import random

# This is the initial counter for the number of cards dealt.
t_counter = 0

# This is the initial counter for the number of aces dealt.
a_counter = 0

# This is the initial counter for the number of face cards dealt.
f_counter = 0

# This is so both a rank and a suit are dealt.
r = random.randint(1,13)
s = random.randint(1,4)

while a_counter < 4:

    # This counts and tells the user of each card dealt that isn't an ace.
    r = random.randint(1,13)
    s = random.randint(1,4)
    t_counter += 1

    if r == 11:
        rank = "Jack"
    elif r == 12:
        rank = "Queen"
    elif r == 13:
        rank = "King"
    elif r > 1:
        rank = r

    if s == 1:
        suit = "Spades"
    elif s == 2:
        suit = "Hearts"
    elif s == 3:
        suit = "Diamonds"
    elif s == 4:
        suit = "Clubs"
    print("Card",t_counter,': A',rank,"of",suit,)

   # This counts the aces.
    if r == 1:
        a_counter += 1
        print("An Ace of",suit,"!")

    # This counts the face cards.
    if r == 11 or r == 12 or r == 13:
        f_counter += 1

    # This allows up to four aces and also prints the number of face cards as the last thing.
    if a_counter == 4:
        print("You got",f_counter,"face cards!")
        break
```

Comment: I ran it a few times and got 8, 16, 30,and 19 as the first few results. You do seem to have a bug where if your first roll of r is a 1, rank doesn't get set and throws an error at the print statement, though.

Comment: Each result will be different since there are a different number of face cards each time. I counted the face cards myself and they were always a little off from what the f_counter said.

Comment: Are you considering the size of the deck or is that not important?

Comment: That's not; he said that each card dealt is completely independent of the previous.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it. Consider the case where you have roll a face card.

> Let r = 11.
>
> rank -> 'Jack'
>
> suit -> anything
>
> print('Jack of whatever')
>
> increment f_counter
>
> // next iteration
>
> Let r = 1
>
> Fall through the if statements that set rank because rank isn't 11,12,13 or > 1, thus rank = 'Jack'
>
> print('jack of some other suit')
>
> Increment a_counter (because rolled r = 1)
>
> Fall through the possibilities to increment f_counter

Thus, you've printed a face card without incrementing f_counter.

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes to your program. Let me know if this gives your desired output and I can explain the main changes.

```
rank = ''

while a_counter < 4:

    # This counts and tells the user of each card dealt that isn't an ace.
    r = random.randint(1,13)
    s = random.randint(1,4)
    t_counter += 1


    if s == 1:
        suit = "Spades"
    elif s == 2:
        suit = "Hearts"
    elif s == 3:
        suit = "Diamonds"
    elif s == 4:
        suit = "Clubs"

    if r == 11:
        rank = "Jack"
        f_counter += 1
    elif r == 12:
        rank = "Queen"
        f_counter += 1
    elif r == 13:
        rank = "King"
        f_counter += 1
    elif r > 1 and r < 11:
        rank = r
    elif r == 1:
        rank == "Ace"
        a_counter += 1

    if r == 1:
        print("Card %d: An Ace of %s! **") % (t_counter, suit)
    else:
        print("Card %d: a %s of %s") % (t_counter, rank, suit)

    if a_counter == 4:
        print("You got %d face cards!") % (f_counter)
        break
```

This seems to be working for me, except there's nothing in your program that would prevent the same card turning up twice (or more)...

Comment: Thank you so much! I switched your print statements with mine because yours weren't printing for some reason, but everything else works (your elif statements make a lot more sense than mine) and the f_counter is counting correctly now. One question I had, though is what's the point of " rank = ' ' "?

Comment: @user6627144 - That's great - please feel free to accept it as the correct answer if it achieves what you want

Comment: @user6627144 I would try and stick with the print statements I have, as it's a more Python-ish way of printing.

Comment: @user6627144 - The `rank = ''` declares rank outside of your loop (like you do for your other variables)